# XML SOAP namespace uses only first 3 chars

Tags: web-services, soap, xsd, wsdl, soapui

Let's assume I have following xsd:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="abcd" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:ebppif1="abcd">
    <xs:element name="Test">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="someValue" type="xs:long"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I followed [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/) to create SOAP web service, which works flawlessly.

But the problem is that namespace is shortened to 'abc' (on SoapIU)

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:abc="abcd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <abc:Test>
         <abc:someValue>123</abc:someValue>
      </abc:Test>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How can I disable or change namespace length shortening to achieve full namespace in requests?

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of XML namespaces is incorrect. A namespace prefix is not a namespace.

The XML document produced by SoapUI is correct. If you check the SoapUI document, the *namespace prefix* 'abc' is correctly mapped to the *namespace* 'abcd'.

I strongly recommend that you take a W3Schools tutorial on XML namespaces. It might seem difficult, but it is actually very straightforward. If you invest some time in learning the basics it will pay off.

Comment: Thanks, I know, it was my one time task. Even if 'abc' is mapped to 'abcd', changing abc in request (prefix) to abcd does not work (Spring can not reconise/parse objects)